# How to redirect submodule calls to parent module in Python

Tags: python, import

My directory structure looks like this:

```
\Module
      |
      __init.py__ (from File1 import File1...)
      File1.py
      File2.py
      \Submodule
              |
               __init.py__ (Empty right now)
```

I can do `Module.File1.run()`.

But I want to do `Module.Submodule.File1.run()` and redirect it to `Module`'s `File1`.

Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to copy all the `Module` files to `Submodule`?

EDIT 1:

If I make a `File1` in `Submodule` (a copy of `Module`'s `File1`) and do `from File1 import File1` in the `__init__` file in `Submodule`, it works.

But if I do `form Module import File1` or `from Module.File1 import File1`, it doesn't work. I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `Module.Submodule.File1` to `Module.File1`:

```
import Module.File1
import Module.Submodule

Module.Submodule.File1 = Module.File1
```

Now this works:

```
Module.Submodule.File1.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a *nix system, you can simply create a symbolic link. On the CLI, use `ln -s`:

```
ln -s ./Module/File1.py ./Module/Submodule/
```

That would create a symbolic link named `./Module/Submodule/File1.py` that points to the original `File1.py`.

---

**Edit**:

Another way would be to import the file in the `__init__.py` of the Submodule. In `./Module/Submodule/__init__.py`:

```
from .. import File1
```

Then you can access it

```
import Module.Submodule
Module.Submodule.File1.run()
```

Comment: I need to keep it platform independent :(

Comment: Added another way to my answer

Comment: I should be able to do this, but it's not working, please see the Edit in my Question.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, this is how to do this:

```
\Module
      |
      __init.py__ (from File1 import File1...)
        > import Submodule
      File1.py
        > def run():
        >   print "RUNNING"
      \Submodule
              |
               __init.py__
                > from Module import File1
```

This is how you call it:

```
import Module`
Module.Submodule.File1.run()`
```

I think you might benifit from a different structure, though.

Comment: I wish I could change structure, but it's mostly supporting legacy calls.

Comment: Notice how I don't use relative imports? If this is legacy you are probably better off this way. Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Makes sense, 2.7.11 The calls are being made from another XML file. That's the legacy part. The python Version is latest

Comment: This is not working, if I make a File1 in Submodule and do from File1 import File1, It works. But if I do form Module import File1 or from Module.File1 import File1, it doesn't work.

Comment: If it is working like that, then it isn't as you described the problem. Looks like you are making a symlink in to your file in order for it to appear to be a file in Submodule. Why not just import the file like in this answer?